# How to repair door jamb damage?

Tags: repair, door-frame, storm-door

My front storm door didn't latch  and   was caught in high winds, resulting in the door frame/jamb being pulled and damaged. I'd like to repair it.

The piece of the door frame that the storm door was attached to is an odd shape. It's close to a 1x1  but narrower on one dimension  and looks   curved on the front. It looks like there might be similar pieces going around that window next to the door.

I'm wondering if it's standard, or I could expect to find it at a big box store?

It also looks like there was an additional shim piece or something on the lower part of the trim.

Pics are here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nUFWec18TIIOAXjFlG4ajjhifbDkkEe3/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RemGtgsSfdlW-7dydeBNqw8LBA5ZGoi5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried to copy and paste the photos to the question but google will not allow it. **Info in posting photo:**  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 0):

I am interested to note that piece of broken wood looks to have been attached using deck screws.  Wood on the other side has nails which I think would be more typical for something like this.

I wonder if that piece was attached just to accept the storm door they had.

You could back into the project.  First find a storm door that will fit the space, then determine what you need to accept the mounting.  Remove the deck screwed broken piece and put up the new piece.

You will need to repaint the whole thing.  Do that before you put up the storm door but after you have the new wood in place.

Comment: yea I tried to secure that wood piece earlier with the bigger screws because of an earlier, similar incident with the wind pulling the door; it pulled this piece out a bit and I noticed it was only held in place with tacks or small nails, or something that looked insufficient
Also I'm trying to figure out if we can put the old door back in; there are a couple metal pieces on top and one on the side where it latches; they all seem intact; I may just hire a guy of Thumbtack, I got a quote; this might just be beyond my meager skills